# How to Detect if a Cell is Changed by an "=IF()" Formula and not by a User

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, cell

I read a lot of pages saying that, but none of them put the solution if the value change by an "if function" not by hand.

The code I get is that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A18:A30")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop
    On Error GoTo Finalize 'to re-enable the events
    MsgBox "You changed THE CELL!"
Finalize:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It only works if I change the value by hand.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel _Occurs when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link._ and _This event does not occur when cells change during a recalculation. Use the Calculate event to trap a sheet recalculation._

Comment: But then I don't have target to compare.

Comment: @David_helo - then you need to think about some type of an architecture. E.g., save the values of `A18:A30` to another sheet and on calculate event compare these every time with the `A18:A30` on the current sheet and give some `MsgBox()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution; instead of triggering your function every time when your worksheet recalculates, add a function in a module:

```
Function DetectChange() As Integer
    MsgBox "You changed THE CELL!"
    DetectChange = 0
End Function
```

Assuming the outcome of your formula is numeric:(otherwise outcome of function must be a empty string and the "+" must be "&")
Add to your IF-formula at the end ...+Detectchange()
Now there will be a msgbox **only** when your formula is recalculated

**Edit** by Darren Bartrup-Cook:

I found this code gave worked when the formula recalculated.  It didn't fire if I changed a cell that doesn't affect the cell it's entered to and it didn't fire using `Calculate Now` or `Calculate Sheet`.
It did occasionally fire for all formula that I used the function in, but that seemed to be when I was debugging - maybe further investigation needed.

```
Public Function DetectChange()
    MsgBox "You changed cell " & Application.Caller.Address
End Function
```

e.g.:
`=IF(A1=1,A2,A3) & DetectChange()` entered in cell A4 displays the message *"You changed cell $A$4"* if cells A1, A2 or A3 is changed.

Comment: I like this idea - you'd have to put `Application.Volatile(False)`, maybe also `Application.EnableEvents = False` and could change the message to `MsgBox "You changed cell " & Application.Caller.Address`.  You don't need it to return anything, so remove the `DetectChange = 0` and the `Integer` return.  Can then be used as `=SUM(B2:B3)+DetectChange()` or `=D2 & D3 & DetectChange()`.  Are a couple of problems when debugging - first update to any cell fires it, but I think that's because it has to recalculate the sheet after code has been paused & been mucked around with.. not sure though.

Comment: @Vityata Yes, and it works.  I'll take a little bit of a liberty and add the exact code I used to the bottom of the post.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - the `MsgBox()` works indeed. Is this something from Excel 2016, in the old versions I recall it did not work.

Comment: @Vityata. No, I'm using 2010. You're not thinking of the "can't change another cell with a UDF" thing which is still the case?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - I had the idea that `MsgBox` are not supported by UDF as well. Obviously it is changing format of the cells and the `MsgBox()` is not in that list.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  thanks for the edits, I don't think the Application. bits are necessary and yes after debugging all formulas with the UDF are recalculated. A msgbox in a function isn't very good practice either, it's just a way to show the function is triggered

Comment: What is the point of disabling events? Marking the function as non-volatile (default) is definitely redundant.

Comment: Bytheway, it is possible to change format of cells by a UDF (in combination with evaluate and a Sub)

Comment: @BrakNicku Absolutely correct - think I was just rushing, the code was firing multiple times after I'd finished debugging so I threw in the disabling events and volatile and then it stopped... I should've checked more thoroughly.

Comment: @EvR As pointed out - the `Application` parts of the code muddy the waters so maybe roll back the edit - or keep the `Caller` part of the message.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, just deleted the Application...parts in the Edit - code

Answer (score 1):

Write this in `Sheet1` and run the `TestMe` sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A30")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo Finalize
    MsgBox "You changed THE CELL!"
Finalize:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub TestMe()
    Range("A1") = 34
End Sub
```

It has worked quite ok on my PC.

---

If the cell is changed by a built-in Excel function, then the comment of @Vincent G states the correct answer:

***Worksheet_Change event*** occurs when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link. and This event does not occur when cells change during a recalculation. Use the Calculate event to trap a sheet recalculation.

---

If you want to track the calclulation event based on some changes at `Range(A18:A30)` this is a working solution:

- Add a new Worksheet to your Workbook (`Sheet2`);
- In the current Worksheet write the Calculate event:

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()        
      Dim cell As Range
      For Each cell In Sheet2.Range("A18:A30")
          If cell <> Sheet1.Range(cell.Address) Then
              cell = Sheet1.Range(cell.Address)
          End If
      Next cell
  End Sub
  ```
- In the `Sheet2` write an event, catching the changes.

Comment: The cell is change by an "If function" not by macro.

Comment: @David_helo - I understood the `If function` as something from the VBA code.

Comment: I get the solution. As @Vincent G says, only using Calculate event

Answer (score 0):

As simple as @Vincent G says.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

     Call YourFunction

End Sub
```