# How to fix msgbox showing up twice When Cell Formula Result Changes?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, worksheet, calculation

I want a msgbox to show up only once when formula result changes in my table range `("K2:K5")`. Right now it shows twice.

In this range I have excel-formulas. Formula: `H12*10`

These formulas is refering to a dropdown-list (a list that I've created from "data validation" on the excel menu Data-tab).

The dropdown-list is located in `cell H12`.
The values in the dropdown is refering to range`(D15:D17)`

I've noticed though that the msgbox shows up once when I remove the dropdown and manualy type in values in `H12`.

Thankful for any help on this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim Xrg As Range
Set Xrg = Range("K2:K5")
If Not Intersect(Xrg, Range("K2:K5")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Hi"
End If
End Sub
```

I have also tried to add `Application.enableEvents` to the code but no success.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim Xrg As Range
Set Xrg = Range("K2:K5")
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Xrg, Range("K2:K5")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Hi"
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Not Intersect(...` will always come out to be true because you're comparing two identical ranges... it has no real value to it

Comment: As per @TimStack his comment, your code has no added value. A simple `Msgbox "Hi"` on the Worksheet_Calculate event would do. Also, if you have more formulas that can trigger the event, you might want to look into `Worksheet_Change` event looking if `Target` would be equal to `H12` cell and if true, return messagebox.

Comment: `Worksheet_Calculate` doesn't give you the exact range where values are being updated, so in your case it is useless. `Worksheet_Change` gives you exact location of the change, but even that would not give you any result if values are being changed using Formula.

Comment: You 'could' add a UDF to your formula in K2:K5 see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495354/how-to-detect-if-a-cell-is-changed-by-an-if-formula-and-not-by-a-user/51496226#51496226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code has no added value on a `Worksheet_Calculate` event due to comparing two exact same ranges and see if they intersect. That would always be the case. Your code would have the same effect as:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    MsgBox "Hi"
End Sub
```

Might you have more functions in your worksheet that could trigger this event unwanted outside range `K2:K5`, you should look into the `Worksheet_Change` event and return a messagebox when your referenced cell has changed value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$H$12" Then MsgBox "Hi"
End Sub
```

Choose either one, but don't use both cause you'll end up with two msgbox's

Comment: Very grateful for your solutions and explanations of how it's put together in a proper manner. It now works as intended. Many thanks!