# Excel VBA - How to detect if a column changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update a date field with Today() whenever my Status column changes, the problem is using the Today() function changes everytime I open the excel sheet.

How do I build a vba function similiar to this post that will tell me if the status field changes?

`=IF(ISBLANK([@Status]),"",TODAY()) && DetectChange()`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496226

Comment: Today() and many other functions are classed as volatile so they will update whenever they are triggered.

Comment: Use the `Worksheet.Change` event to write a timestamp. Many many similar questions on this site or across the web.

Comment: @SolarMike i agree,, that's why i wanted a 2nd boolean to actually to do Today()